# On even cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\Phi_n$ be the nth cyclotomic polynomial.

I would like to show that if $4$ divides $n$, then $\Phi_n$ is even. Any idea ?

Comment: @egreg http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85828/how-to-prove-whether-a-polynomial-function-is-even-or-odd

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- if $n=4k$, then $\phi(n)=\deg(\Phi_n(x))$ is even
- $z$ is a $4k$-th primitive root if and only if $\;-z\;$ is

Now write the cyclotomic polynomial as product of linear factors and conclude